# Add a text after pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, replace

Is there a way to add some text after pattern in python string?

For example I can do it easily with `sed`:

```
sed 's/my [a-z]\+ pattern/& lost_text/'
```

where `&` means the whole matched pattern.

search and man pages didn't help me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)',r'\1--','abcd1cf123vf')
'abcd1--cf123--vf'
```

Comment: Oh, that was so easy. I've searched in incorrect direction. Thank you. :)

Comment: It's impossible to accept the answer immediately due to restrictions in SO engine. So I did it only now.